# How to make aws databse work in android?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

so I'm trying to set up an aws database and im following the tutorial for set up here : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/getting-started-store-query-app-data.html

But none of the imports work! When i import the following:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.*;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.*;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBAttribute;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBHashKey;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBScanExpression;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBTable;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.PaginatedScanList;
```

All of them have a red line error!

Here is my dependencies.

```
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.3.3'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.3.3'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.3.3'
    compile('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobileanalytics:2.3.3')
    compile('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-apigateway-core:2.3.3')
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognitoidentityprovider:2.3.3'
```

So because of this i cannot make the basic objects necessary to store data into my aws database... I get redline errors below. I hope you guys can help!

```
    AmazonDynamoDBClient ddbClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentialsProvider);
    DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(ddbClient);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store data using DynamoDB, you need to give some permissions.

### Set Permissions in Your Android Manifest

In `AndroidManifest.xml`, set the following permission, if it’s not already present

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

A step by step storing data is given in the link: [Store and Retrieve App Data in Amazon DynamoDB](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/dynamodb_om.html)